# How to mock a method that calls other methods that are present in the same class

Tags: java, unit-testing, spring-boot, mockito, spring-batch

I an new to Mockito. I am writing Tests for a class using Mockito. I have a method that calls other methods of the same class. How would I mock this method? I have posted the class for which I am trying to write the Tests for. I am trying to mock the method process(PersonDTO person)

```
public class Processor {
    @Autowired
    private SomeService service;

    @Autowired
    private SomeServiceProperties properties;

    private Util util = new Util();

    public SPMOutboundVO process(PersonDTO person) throws Exception {
        SPMOutboundVO outboundVO = null;
        if(validatePersonForBenefitsProcessing(person)) {
            PersonPayrollFromWorkdayVO personPayrollFromWorkdayVO = service.getPersonPayrollFromWorkday(util.getStartOrEndDate(DayOfWeek.SUNDAY),util.getStartOrEndDate(DayOfWeek.SATURDAY),person.getEmployeeID());
            if(personPayrollFromWorkdayVO != null) {
                person.setBillingStartDate(getPayrollPeriod(personPayrollFromWorkdayVO));
                person.setAmount(util.getMonthlyDiscountPayRate(person.getPayPeriod(),getDiscountRate(personPayrollFromWorkdayVO)));
            }
            if(isNewLeave(person,getPayrollPeriod(personPayrollFromWorkdayVO))) {
                person.setBillingStartDate(getPayrollPeriod(personPayrollFromWorkdayVO));
                outboundVO = processOutboundSPMInsertRecords(person);
            } else if (person.isReturnFromLeaveOrTermed()){
                person.setBillingEndDate(person.getFirstDayBackAtWorkMinus1());
                outboundVO = processOutboundSPMUpdateRecords(person);
            }
        }
        return outboundVO;
    }

    public boolean validatePersonForBenefitsProcessing(PersonDTO person) {

        // Some code
    }

    public SPMOutboundVO processOutboundSPMInsertRecords(PersonDTO person) {
       // Some code
    }

    public SPMOutboundVO processOutboundSPMUpdateRecords(PersonDTO person) {
        // Some code
    }

    public String getPayrollPeriod(PersonPayrollFromWorkdayVO personPayrollFromWorkdayVO) {
        // Some code
    }

    public boolean isNewLeave(PersonDTO, String) {
        // Some code
    }

}
```

Comment: You don't mock other parts of the same class. Mock its *collaborators*.

Comment: @jonrsharpe OK. I am very new to Mockito. I sure did some reading before I started trying to write the tests. By collaborators, do you mean the other dependecnies - like the service instance that I use in the class? Also, if other parts of the same class are not mocked, then do I just mock the return value from the method call and proceed?

Comment: Yes, the dependencies. If those methods are only used from process, they shouldn't even be public.

Comment: Ok. One add-on question. By marking the methods private, would the test/code coverage take a hit?

Comment: Why *would* it? Try it and see.

Comment: Yes, I am going to try it now.

Comment: When unittesting we verify *public observable behavior* of the code under test, that is *return values* and *communication with dependencies*.

Anything else is *implementation detail* which we do not test. The reason is that you might want to *refactor* your code. That means you want to improve the *structure* of your code without changing its *behavior*. Your unittest schould verify that you did not change behavior accidentally. But they can only do this if you do not have to change them too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, technically, you can mock selected methods from a class with mockito.  This feature is called partial mocking.  It is explained in the mockito documentation: https://static.javadoc.io/org.mockito/mockito-core/3.0.0/org/mockito/Mockito.html#partial_mocks.

Second: There are cases when it makes sense while testing a class to mock other methods from that same class.  A good example would be a method (for the sake of example let's call it `do_interactions`) that bundles interactions with other components, such that the remaining methods of the class are free of such interactions and only call `do_interactions` for that purpose.  To be more concrete, think of a method that delivers a file's content for other methods: it bundles the interaction with the operating system like opening and reading and just returns the content.  Then, you can easily perform tests in isolation from the operating system just by mocking that function to have it return the 'simluated' file contents as your tests need them.

That said, there are example where such mocking makes sense, but this does not necessarily apply in your situation.

Third, testing is about findings bugs (see Myers, Badgett, Sandler: The Art of Software Testing, or, Beizer: Software Testing Techniques, and many others), unit-testing aims at findings those bugs which can be found in the isolated code.  To be effective in finding bugs you will have to have implementation specific tests: Bugs are in the implementation, different implementations have different bugs.  Think of the vast amount of sorting algorithms: They all have the same API, but their implementations are totally different.  Or, think about ways to implement a Fibonacci function: as an iterative or recursive function, as a closed form expression (Moivre/Binet), or as a lookup table.  Again, the interface is always the same, the possible bugs differ significantly, and so do the unit-testing strategies.  And, unit-testing is the testing level that is closest to the implementation level - integration-testing, subsystem-testing and system-testing are way up and thus less suited to find bugs in the implementation.  Therefore, trying to remain implementation agnostic in your unit-tests is likely to result in a less effective test-suite.

That said, it is true that you also should strive for low test maintenance effort.  This means, don't make a test case implementation specific if that is not necessary for that specific test.  And, for those tests that for good reason are implementation specific, still try to keep the maintenance effort low, for example by extracting the implementation specific parts of the tests in helper methods, to reduce the amount of test code you have to maintain in case of changes to the SUT (see [[Meszaros: Principles of Test Automation: Ensure Commensurate Effort](http://xunitpatterns.com/Principles%20of%20Test%20Automation.html#Ensure%20Commensurate%20Effort%20and%20Responsibility)]).